# On page load, if checkbox is checked, show field

Tags: javascript

So I have the below code that shows/hides fields depending if the checkbox is checked, but I can't seem to figure out when I refresh the page and my sample data on my form that is saved, has the checkmark already checked, why my fields are not showing on page load.

```
On page load (With saved data):  
- First checkbox checked (Shows nothing)  
- Uncheck then check, then it finally shows
```

**How can I make the fields show on page load when the checkbox is checked? I've tried calling the DOMContentLoaded but am I doing it correctly?**

[image]

**Code**:

```
const formWrapperPersonal = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-personal');

var rtk11 = document.getElementById('rtk1');
function rtk1() {
    rtk11.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        if (e.target.checked) {
            formWrapperPersonal.style.display = ''
        } else {
            formWrapperPersonal.style.display = 'none'
        }
    })
}
rtk11.addEventListener('change', rtk1);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtk1);
rtk1();
```

Comment: Remove the `addEventListener` inside the `rtk1` method

Comment: @Taplar, if I remove that, would I target it using `if (rtk11.target.checked) {` instead of `if (e.target.checked) {`?

Comment: `rtk11.checked`, in the case that you call `rtk1();` directly there is no event to get the target off of

Comment: Please make it the official answer - Worked like a charm @Taplar, thanks a bunch!

Comment: Thanks so much also @Light, both worked.

Comment: Actually light's did not work, as it was using `this`.  And as previously mentioned, `this` would not be the element outside of the event handler invocation

Comment: Ahh, didn't even realize that @Taplar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the inner event listener as you already have one on the element and the document.

```
const formWrapperPersonal = document.getElementById('form-wrapper-personal');

var rtk11 = document.getElementById('rtk1');
function rtk1() {
    if (rtk11.checked) {
        formWrapperPersonal.style.display = ''
    } else {
        formWrapperPersonal.style.display = 'none'
    }
}

rtk11.addEventListener('change', rtk1);
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', rtk1);
rtk1();
```